# E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table Users_Table has no column named Monday_Calories

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, android-database

Im doing a database which will store user data, username password age gender height email and weight are inputed by the user and the values for the other columns are left as 0.0. when i debug the app i get the following error 
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table Users_Table has no column named Monday_Calories 
The Error is from the User table, the Product table has not been called yet.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //DATABASE VERSION
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //DATABASE NAME
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AppDatabase";
    //TABLE NAMES
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "Users_Table";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "Products_Table";
    //COMMON COLUMN NAMES
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "User_ID";
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCT_ID = "Product_ID";
    //USER TABLE
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "Username";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "Age";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_GENDER = "Gender";
    private static final String KEY_HEIGHT = "Height";
    private static final String KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT = "Current_Weight";
    private static final String KEY_START_WEIGHT = "Start_Weight";
    private static final String KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE = "Weight_Change";
    private static final String KEY_BMI = "BMI";
    private static final String KEY_BMR = "BMR";
    private static final String KEY_MON_CAL = "Monday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_TUES_CAL = "Tuesday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_WED_CAL = "Wednesday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_THUR_CAL = "Thursday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_FRI_CAL = "Friday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_SAT_CAL = "Saturday_Calories";
    private static final String KEY_SUN_CAL = "Sunday_Calories";
    //PRODUCT TABLE
    private static final String KEY_ITEMNAME = "Item_name";
    private static final String KEY_ITEMCALORIES = "Item_Calories";
    //
    private static final String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "( "
            + KEY_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_AGE + " INTEGER, "
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_HEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_START_WEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_BMI + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_BMR + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_MON_CAL + "DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_TUES_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_WED_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_THUR_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_FRI_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_SAT_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_SUN_CAL + " DOUBLE ); ";

    private static final String CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "( " + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_ITEMNAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_ITEMCALORIES + " DOUBLE );";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCT_TABLE);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF IT EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    //CRUD OPERATIONS
    public Users getUser(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS,
                new String[]{ KEY_USER_ID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_AGE,
                        KEY_EMAIL, KEY_GENDER, KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_START_WEIGHT,
                        KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT, KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE, KEY_BMI, KEY_BMR},
                KEY_USER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor!= null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Users users = new Users(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2), cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getDouble(6), cursor.getDouble(7), cursor.getDouble(8), cursor.getDouble(9),
                cursor.getDouble(10), cursor.getDouble(11), cursor.getDouble(12), cursor.getDouble(13),
                cursor.getDouble(14), cursor.getDouble(15), cursor.getDouble(16), cursor.getDouble(17), cursor.getDouble(18) );
        return users;

    }
    public void addUser(Users users){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, users.get_username());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, users.get_password());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, users.get_age());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, users.get_email());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, users.get_gender());
        values.put(KEY_HEIGHT, users.get_height());
        values.put(KEY_START_WEIGHT, users.get_startWeight());
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT, users.get_currentWeight());
        values.put(KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE, users.get_weightChange());
        values.put(KEY_BMI, users.get_BMI());
        values.put(KEY_BMR, users.get_BMR());
        values.put(KEY_MON_CAL, users.get_monCal());
        values.put(KEY_TUES_CAL, users.get_tuesCal());
        values.put(KEY_WED_CAL, users.get_wedCal());
        values.put(KEY_THUR_CAL, users.get_thurCal());
        values.put(KEY_FRI_CAL, users.get_friCal());
        values.put(KEY_SAT_CAL, users.get_satCal());
        values.put(KEY_SUN_CAL, users.get_sunCal());

        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public  int getUserCount(){
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;

    }

    public int updateUser(Users users){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, users.get_username());
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, users.get_password());
        values.put(KEY_AGE, users.get_age());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, users.get_email());
        values.put(KEY_GENDER, users.get_gender());
        values.put(KEY_HEIGHT, users.get_height());
        values.put(KEY_START_WEIGHT, users.get_startWeight());
        values.put(KEY_CURRENT_WEIGHT, users.get_currentWeight());
        values.put(KEY_WEIGHT_CHANGE, users.get_weightChange());
        values.put(KEY_BMI, users.get_BMI());
        values.put(KEY_BMR, users.get_BMR());
        values.put(KEY_MON_CAL, users.get_monCal());
        values.put(KEY_TUES_CAL, users.get_tuesCal());
        values.put(KEY_WED_CAL, users.get_wedCal());
        values.put(KEY_THUR_CAL, users.get_thurCal());
        values.put(KEY_FRI_CAL, users.get_friCal());
        values.put(KEY_SAT_CAL, users.get_satCal());
        values.put(KEY_SUN_CAL, users.get_sunCal());

        return db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, KEY_USER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(users.get_id())});
    }
    public List<Users> getallUsers(){
        List<Users> usersList = new ArrayList<Users>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Users users = new Users();
                users.set_id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                users.set_username(cursor.getString(1));
                users.set_password(cursor.getString(2));
                users.set_age(cursor.getInt(3));
                users.set_email(cursor.getString(4));
                users.set_gender(cursor.getString(5));
                users.set_height(cursor.getDouble(6));
                users.set_startWeight(cursor.getDouble(7));
                users.set_currentWeight(cursor.getDouble(8));
                users.set_weightChange();
                users.set_BMI(cursor.getDouble(10));
                users.set_BMR(cursor.getDouble(11));
                users.set_monCal(cursor.getDouble(12));
                users.set_tuesCal(cursor.getDouble(13));
                users.set_wedCal(cursor.getDouble(14));
                users.set_thurCal(cursor.getDouble(15));
                users.set_friCal(cursor.getDouble(16));
                users.set_satCal(cursor.getDouble(17));
                users.set_sunCal(cursor.getDouble(18));
                usersList.add(users);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        return usersList;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your column is named `Monday_CaloriesDOUBLE`, because you miss a space here

```
 + KEY_MON_CAL + "DOUBLE, "
```

It must be

```
 + KEY_MON_CAL + " DOUBLE, "
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that, Thanks very much for your help.